# How many copies of site.py should I have?

Tags: python, path, package

My understanding of the role of Python's `site.py` is that it provides site-wide configuration (e.g. setting of paths). That leads me to expect that there should be *one* such file for each version of Python I have installed, but for at least one of my installations (2.7.5 on OS X 10.9) I have *two*, one in
   `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python` 
and another in 
   `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/`. Which of these is actually used? Are both? Can I remove one to tidy things up; if so, which?

---

The same question applies for `easy_install.py` and `pkg_resources.py`, which are also duplicated in the same way.

Comment: Are you sure that none of them are linked - try `ls -l` in the directories.

Comment: @SteveBarnes: No links.